# PowerBI Count the number of rows in table that is created with field parameters

Tags: parameters, powerbi, dax, field

I created a table in which a user can select the desired columns with a field parameter.

Now i want to create a measure to display the amount of rows that are now inside this table.
Right now the Countrows function will always display the maximum amount of rows.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you post sample data and a .pbix with desired outcome.

Comment: Why are you still asking on Stack Overflow if not a single answer here has satisfied you yet?